# I have Changed custom admin URL from admin panel,not working and getting admin url 404 error.

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database

> I have Changed custom admin URL from admin panel,not working and
>   getting admin url 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The pages you are talking about are specific to PHPMyAdmin, to help
>   user have a more understandable interface, by only showing a specific
>   number of rows. So it doesn't really matter which page they are, and
>   it would change from a project to another.
>
> What you need to do is look for the path you want with a SQL query (or
>   with a search if you are using phpmyadmin or a similar tool).
>
> You could use this request :

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%";
```

> This will select all the rows where the path contains "admin/url/",
>   then you should be able to modify them.
>
> After see attached screenshot, if you find different value,please run
>   this below update query.[image]

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`config_id` = 371;
```

> You can also put value zero manually. Note down **`config_id` = 371;**
>   might be different,so please check same value and update.
>
> Reload your store URL, if changes not reflect then clear your browser 
>   cache.
>
> I hope It's helpful for you.

Comment: Your screenshot and update query solved my problem, Thank You lot @Umesh

Answer (score 2):

Go to **app/etc/local.xml**

Add your new url path like "custom_admin_url"

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[custom_admin_url]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Delete `var/cache` and check.

Comment: Not working bro@Sagar

Comment: please run this query in db SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%admin/url/%"

Comment: you can get any result?

Comment: no something very wrong done from my side,BTW thank you@Sagar

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

Visit your `local.xml` which will be in app/etc

Find:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

The [admin] section will be your URL.

Update this, refresh your browser cache. See if it works.

Comment: i am already  tried this but not working any more@Nikunj Vadariya

Answer (score 0):

Firstly clear cache.

Suppose if your admin is: **myadmin**

And your domain name is: www.testing.com

Then try following URLs

**www.testing.com/myadmin**

If above not working then try

**www.testing.com/index.php/myadmin**